# How to automatically activate virtualenvs when cd'ing into a directory

Tags: virtualenv, zsh, oh-my-zsh, virtualenvwrapper, direnv

I have a bunch of projects in my `~/Documents`. I work almost exclusively in python, so these are basically all python projects. Each one, e.g. `~/Documents/foo` has its own virtualenv, `~/Documents/foo/venv` (they're always called venv). Whenever I switch between projects, which is ~10 times a day, I do

```
deactivate
cd ..
cd foo
source venv/bin/activate
```

I've reached the point where I'm sick of typing `deactivate` and `source venv/bin/activate`. **I'm looking for a way to just `cd ../foo` and have the virtualenv operations handled for me.**

- I'm familiar with [VirtualEnvWrapper](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) which is a little heavy-handed in my opinion. It seems to move all your virtualenvs somewhere else, and adds a little more complexity than it removes, as far as I can tell. (Dissenting opinions welcome!)
- I am not too familiar with shell scripting. If you can recommend a low-maintenance script to add to my `~/.zshrc` that accomplishes this, that would be more than enough, but from some quick googling, I haven't found such a script.
- I'm a `zsh`/[`oh-my-zsh`](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh) user. `oh-my-zsh` doesn't seem to have a plugin for this. The best answer to this question would be someone contributing an `oh-my-zsh` plugin which does this. (Which I might do if the answers here are lackluster.

Comment: It is not a good idea to overload "cd", the most basic executable. I recommend creating a function called cdd or ccd... that way you keep the original functionality of cd unchanged and you add the funcitonality you want at the cost of pressing twice the 'c' button (ccd) or the 'd' button (cdd).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Put something like this in your .zshrc

```
function cd() {
  if [[ -d ./venv ]] ; then
    deactivate
  fi

  builtin cd $1

  if [[ -d ./venv ]] ; then
    . ./venv/bin/activate
  fi
}
```

**Edit**: As noted in comments `cd`-ing into a subfolder of the current virtual env would deactivate it. One idea could be to deactivate the current env only if `cd`-ing into a new one, like

```
function cd() {
  builtin cd $1

  if [[ -n "$VIRTUAL_ENV" && -d ./venv ]] ; then
    deactivate
    . ./venv/bin/activate
  fi
}
```

that could still be improved, maybe turning it into a "prompt command" or [attempting some prefix matching](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6435/how-to-check-if-pwd-is-a-subdirectory-of-a-given-path) on the folder names to check there's a virtual env somewhere up the path, but my shell-fu is not good enough.

Comment: Hi @agnul. Thanks for this answer! Why `. ./venv/bin/activate`  instead of `source venv/bin/activate/` ?

Comment: "." is equivalent to "source", at least for zsh and bash

Comment: `[[ -d ./venv ]]` works only if current directory is the root of the project. Better test for env var: `[ -n "$VIRTUAL_ENV" ]`.

Comment: As phd points out, if I cd into a subdirectory of a project with a virtualenv, I step out of the virtualenv. However, @phd's solution isn't working for me at all. Would one of you be willing to help with this? How do I stay in the virtualenv when I'm in a directory with a virtualenv anywhere above?

Comment: Still looking for an answer to this one!

Comment: is there any reason at all to run `deactivate`? e.g. if you exit the shell with `ctr+d` then won't the session be automatically closed?

Comment: I think it should be:
`function cd() {
  builtin cd $1

  if [[ -d venv ]] ; then
    if [[ -n "$VIRTUAL_ENV" ]] ; then
      deactivate
    fi
    source venv/bin/activate
  fi
}`

Comment: This will also not switch environments when you cd from one env to another; it will only deactivate the new one, but not activate the new one.

Comment: @AlexLenail this is because you cannot fix it in a couple of lines, within your `.zshrc`, but you need something more...look at the [autoenv](https://github.com/inishchith/autoenv) and [direnv](https://direnv.net) solutions, I provided in my answer here below ;)

Comment: checking on `$PWD` value?

Answer (score 63):

Add following in your .bashrc or .zshrc

```
function cd() {
  builtin cd "$@"

  if [[ -z "$VIRTUAL_ENV" ]] ; then
    ## If env folder is found then activate the vitualenv
      if [[ -d ./.env ]] ; then
        source ./.env/bin/activate
      fi
  else
    ## check the current folder belong to earlier VIRTUAL_ENV folder
    # if yes then do nothing
    # else deactivate
      parentdir="$(dirname "$VIRTUAL_ENV")"
      if [[ "$PWD"/ != "$parentdir"/* ]] ; then
        deactivate
      fi
  fi
}
```

This code will not deactivate the virtualenv even if someone goes into subfolder. Inspired by answers of [@agnul](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45217291/8694152) and [@Gilles](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/6454).

If the virtualenv is made by pipenv, then please consider [this wiki page](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/wiki/Run-pipenv-shell-automatically).

Furthermore, for added security please consider [direnv](https://github.com/direnv/direnv).

Comment: just saw this doesn't work if you're in a project with venv and do cd ../other_proj

Comment: @aivision2020 For clarification: Are the names of virtual environment folder in both the projects are `.env`? This code assumes the folder name for virtual environment folder to be `.env`.

Comment: I believe you meant `./env` instead of `.env` in your previous comment, other than that your solution is exactly what I needed.

Comment: @boliva I mean `./.env`, i.e., `.env` folder in the current python project folder. So you current project virtualenv folder should be a hidden folder with name `.env`. Hope that helps.

Comment: right, but your code snippet references `./env` (not to be pedantic though, I was just pointing it out for clarity and to avoid confusions between the posted code and your comment)

Comment: @boliva Thanks for pointing that out. I have the updated the code accordingly.

Comment: note that this snippet works for virtual folders that have been named .env. If you named your folder any other name, change it in the line that says `source ./.env/bin/activate`. The folder name is what you specified when running `mkvirtualenv venv -p python3`. You can also `ls` your current directory to see if you can recognize what you named it.

Comment: It looks to me that cd-ing from a dir with venv to another dir with venv would run deactivate, then nothing? I expect the script to deactivate the old one, and activate the new one.

Comment: @Gauthier simply grab the first block between the `if` and `else` (not inclusive), and put it after the second last `fi`.

Comment: @Ari Yeah, I formulated it as a question, but it was more a comment. Check out my own answer.

Comment: You should consider using the function `chpwd` instead of `cd`. That will work with AUTOCD too.

Comment: I created a plugin for zsh following your reasoning, @MS_. See here: https://github.com/DanielAtKrypton/viper-env

Comment: Is there a way to make it recognize switching between two different projects with two different virtual env names?

Comment: Probably want to use .venv consistently to not conflict with `.env` files or directories for `python-dotenv`. Also recommended in official docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html#creating-virtual-environments

Answer (score 22):

You should try something like [autoenv](https://github.com/inishchith/autoenv) if not [direnv](https://direnv.net).

The first one is considered to be "*lightweight*", while the second one "*simply, higher quality software*", listening respectively to each one's author, talking about the other one's project. Thus, they seem to me fairly good options, to try both!

Anyway, both have been tested on `zsh` shells.
In particular, `autoenv` is really simple to use, after installing it:

```
$ git clone git://github.com/inishchith/autoenv.git ~/.autoenv
$ echo 'source ~/.autoenv/activate.sh' >> ~/.bashrc
```

just "*follow the white rabbit* " and try for example

```
$ mkdir project
$ echo "echo 'whoa'" > project/.env
$ cd project
whoa
```

"If a directory contains a `.env` file, it will automatically be executed when you `cd` into it. When enabled (set `AUTOENV_ENABLE_LEAVE` to a non-null string), if a directory contains a `.env.leave` file, it will automatically be executed when you leave it."

Have a look at https://github.com/inishchith/autoenv for more detailed instructions!...

Comment: Thank you for not simply recommending a library, but additionally including both an explanation as well as command line syntax. That’s a best practice on Stack Overflow, but one that many newer contributors fail to adhere to.

Comment: I strongly agree with you (this was my very first answer, though!), with a bit more explanations, this is something similar to what @mc_kaiser already pointed out.

Answer (score 18):

Rather than writing a custom script you could use [direnv](https://github.com/direnv/direnv). It's not a zsh specific solution (for that you could try [zsh-autoenv](https://github.com/Tarrasch/zsh-autoenv)), but is well-maintained and easy to use with zsh. Once you've installed it, you'd want to put `eval "$(direnv hook zsh)"` at the end of your `.zshrc`. At that point you can do:

```
$ source ~/.zshrc
$ cd foo
$ echo "layout python" > .envrc
direnv: error .envrc is blocked. Run `direnv allow` to approve its content.
$ direnv allow
direnv: loading .envrc
direnv: export +VIRTUAL_ENV ~PATH
```

Now you should be in your virtualenv. You can test by running `pip freeze` to see that your virtualenv specific packages are installed. To deactivate

```
$ cd ..
direnv: unloading
```

Comment: This is the best solution IMO. One thing to note is that adding "layout python" requires the project to conform to a particular structure. See https://direnv.net/man/direnv-stdlib.1.html.

If you structure your project slightly differently (perhaps your virtualenv lives under .venv), you could instead add the line: "PATH_add .venv/bin".

Answer (score 14):

By **far** the easiest option (in 2019+) is to add `virtualenvwrapper` into your `~/.zshrc` `plugins`

For example:

```
plugins=(
  git pip python brew virtualenvwrapper
)
```

Comment: https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/tree/master/plugins/virtualenvwrapper documentation is here.

Answer (score 11):

For anyone using (or considering to use) [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) this can be achieved very conveniently using the [pyenv-virtualenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-virtualenv) plugin as described [here](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-virtualenv#activate-virtualenv).

Basically you simply add a `.python-version` file to the directory in which the name of the virtualenv is specified.

Comment: I think this only works for virtualenvs that are created and managed by `pyenv-virtualenv`. Unless I'm mistaken, this mechanism isn't designed to pick up a local `venv/` subdirectory, only venvs that are in the managed venv directory `$(pyenv root)/versions`, and thus were created by `pyenv-virtualenv` itself.

Answer (score 7):

This is a zsh only solution.

This is an improvement over [daveruinseverything's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56309561/1772898) which is an improvement over [MS_'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50830617/1772898).

We are using `precmd` hook instead of overwriting `cd`.

We have added another extra feature. Suppose the directory structure is

```
├── .venv
│   ├── bin
│   │   └── activate
├── subdir
│   ├── subdir1
│   │   ├── subdir2
│   │   │   └── test2.txt
│   │   └── test1.txt
│   └── test.txt
└── testing.py
```

If you now open a new terminal in subdir2, or directly `cd` to subdir2 from other place, it will activate the venv.

The solution is:

```
autoload -Uz add-zsh-hook
add-zsh-hook precmd automatically_activate_python_venv

function automatically_activate_python_venv() {
  if [[ -z $VIRTUAL_ENV ]] ; then
    activate_venv
  else
    parentdir="$(dirname ${VIRTUAL_ENV})"
    if [[ "$PWD"/ != "$parentdir"/* ]] ; then
      deactivate
      activate_venv
    fi
  fi
}

function activate_venv() {  
  local d n
  d=$PWD
  
  until false 
  do 
  if [[ -f $d/.venv/bin/activate ]] ; then 
    source $d/.venv/bin/activate
    break
  fi
    d=${d%/*}
    # d="$(dirname "$d")"
    [[ $d = *\/* ]] || break
  done
}
```

Comment: it would be great if you could evaluate the functionality of the plugin I created based on your answer. More information [here](https://github.com/DanielAtKrypton/viper-env). Pull requests are welcome!

Comment: @DanielKaminskideSouza I am glad that someone found the code useful enough to make a plugin out of it. I am feeling very good. Thank you very much.

Comment: your research led to I believe the best solution so far. The plugin is a continuation of your research... I just added a feature to work with any environment name and made some speed optimizations.

Answer (score 5):

For posterity: I used @MS_'s solution but ran into the problem where `cd`ing directly from one project to another deactivates the old virtualenv but doesn't activate the new one. This is a slightly modified version of that solution which solves this problem:

```sh
# auto activate virtualenv
# Modified solution based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45216663/how-to-automatically-activate-virtualenvs-when-cding-into-a-directory/56309561#56309561
function cd() {
  builtin cd "$@"

  ## Default path to virtualenv in your projects
  DEFAULT_ENV_PATH="./env"

  ## If env folder is found then activate the vitualenv
  function activate_venv() {
    if [[ -f "${DEFAULT_ENV_PATH}/bin/activate" ]] ; then 
      source "${DEFAULT_ENV_PATH}/bin/activate"
      echo "Activating ${VIRTUAL_ENV}"
    fi
  }

  if [[ -z "$VIRTUAL_ENV" ]] ; then
    activate_venv
  else
    ## check the current folder belong to earlier VIRTUAL_ENV folder
    # if yes then do nothing
    # else deactivate then run a new env folder check
      parentdir="$(dirname ${VIRTUAL_ENV})"
      if [[ "$PWD"/ != "$parentdir"/* ]] ; then
        echo "Deactivating ${VIRTUAL_ENV}"
        deactivate
        activate_venv
      fi
  fi
}
```

Answer (score 4):

that is the solution without **cd'ing**, with zsh set to `setop auto_cd` w'll be able to change directories without cd, just type directory name and hit enter.
it is anhence of above solution:

```
    # auto activate virtualenv
# Modified solution based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45216663/how-to-automatically-activate-virtualenvs-when-cding-into-a-directory/56309561#56309561
function auto_active_env() {

  ## Default path to virtualenv in your projects
  DEFAULT_ENV_PATH="./env"

  ## If env folder is found then activate the vitualenv
  function activate_venv() {
    if [[ -f "${DEFAULT_ENV_PATH}/bin/activate" ]] ; then 
      source "${DEFAULT_ENV_PATH}/bin/activate"
      echo "Activating ${VIRTUAL_ENV}"
    fi
  }

  if [[ -z "$VIRTUAL_ENV" ]] ; then
    activate_venv
  else
    ## check the current folder belong to earlier VIRTUAL_ENV folder
    # if yes then do nothing
    # else deactivate then run a new env folder check
      parentdir="$(dirname ${VIRTUAL_ENV})"
      if [[ "$PWD"/ != "$parentdir"/* ]] ; then
        echo "Deactivating ${VIRTUAL_ENV}"
        deactivate
        activate_venv
      fi
  fi
}
chpwd_functions=(${chpwd_functions[@]} "auto_active_env")
```

Answer (score 2):

Similar to [Jake's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58332379/8844026) but supports `cd`ing from one virtualenv to another. In this case it deactivates the old virtualenv then activates the new one.

```sh
function cd() {
  builtin cd "$@"

  if [[ ! -z "$VIRTUAL_ENV" ]] ; then
    # If the current directory is not contained
    # within the venv parent directory -> deactivate the venv.
    cur_dir=$(pwd -P)
    venv_dir="$(dirname "$VIRTUAL_ENV")"
    if [[ "$cur_dir"/ != "$venv_dir"/* ]] ; then
      deactivate
    fi
  fi

  if [[ -z "$VIRTUAL_ENV" ]] ; then
    # If config file is found -> activate the vitual environment
    venv_cfg_filepath=$(find . -maxdepth 2 -type f -name 'pyvenv.cfg' 2> /dev/null)
    if [[ -z "$venv_cfg_filepath" ]]; then
      return # no config file found
    fi

    venv_filepath=$(cut -d '/' -f -2 <<< ${venv_cfg_filepath})
    if [[ -d "$venv_filepath" ]] ; then
      source "${venv_filepath}"/bin/activate
    fi
  fi
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is (yet) another solution to automatically activate a virtual environment; it's based on a number of the answers already posted here.

This will work for **any** Virtual Environment name or directory (not just `./env`, `./venv`, etc.). Also supports subdirectories, as well as `cd`-ing into symlinks of virtual environment (parent) folders.

This code searches for a `pyvenv.cfg` file instead of a particular named directory. If one is found within a subdirectory of the current folder, the environment is automatically activated. Once inside a virtual environment, that state is retained until you move out of the parent virtual environment directory, at which point the environment is deactivated.

Place this inside your `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`.

```
function cd() {
  builtin cd "$@"

  if [[ -z "$VIRTUAL_ENV" ]] ; then
      # If config file is found -> activate the vitual environment
      venv_cfg_filepath=$(find . -maxdepth 2 -type f -name 'pyvenv.cfg' 2> /dev/null)
      if [[ -z "$venv_cfg_filepath" ]]; then
        return # no config file found
      fi

      venv_filepath=$(cut -d '/' -f -2 <<< ${venv_cfg_filepath})
      if [[ -d "$venv_filepath" ]] ; then
        source "${venv_filepath}"/bin/activate
      fi
  else
    # If the current directory is not contained 
    # within the venv parent directory -> deactivate the venv.
      cur_dir=$(pwd -P)
      venv_dir="$(dirname "$VIRTUAL_ENV")"
      if [[ "$cur_dir"/ != "$venv_dir"/* ]] ; then
        deactivate
      fi
  fi
}
```

Personally I think it's an improvement on a lot of the solutions here, since it should work for any virtual environment

Answer (score 1):

I tried direnv as suggested by others but found it a bit too opinionated and it didn't exactly do what I wanted.

The solution below is for **fish shell users only**. Also, it assumes a `pyproject.toml` file and stdlib's `venv`, but that can be easily changed.

The fish shell has the concept of [event handlers](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/language.html#event-handlers) so you can easily define a function that gets run whenever an "event" gets triggered (Unix signals, environment variables changing, etc). See [this a blog post](https://brettterpstra.com/2019/10/15/fish-shell-fun-event-handlers/) for a quick introduction.

Add the following to your `~/.config/fish/config.fish` (and modify as needed):

```bash
function venv_activate --on-variable PWD
    if test ! -e pyproject.toml
        if test -n "$VIRTUAL_ENV"
            deactivate
        end
        return
    end

    # echo "Found pyproject.toml"
    if test ! -d .venv
        # echo "Creating $(python -V) venv"
        python -m venv .venv --prompt (basename (pwd))
    end

    source .venv/bin/activate.fish
end
```

As a side note, the above works nicely with `pyenv`'s `.python-version` files as well.

Comment: This only activates the venv at the directory where pyproject.toml is. It won't work on subdirectories, but can be modified if needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a zsh hook function that runs whenever you change directories. For example, you could add this to your ~/.zshrc:

```
# Define a function to activate/deactivate virtualenvs based on the current directory
function venv_cd() {
  # Check if the current directory has a venv subdirectory
  if [[ -d venv ]]; then
    # If yes, activate it if it's not already active
    if [[ "$VIRTUAL_ENV" != "$PWD/venv" ]]; then
      source venv/bin/activate
    fi
  else
    # If no, deactivate the current virtualenv if any
    if [[ -n "$VIRTUAL_ENV" ]]; then
      deactivate
    fi
  fi
}
```

Add the function to the chpwd hook, which runs after every cd

```
add-zsh-hook chpwd venv_cd
```

Optionally, run the function once at the start of the session

```
venv_cd
```

This should automatically activate the virtualenv in the current directory if it exists, or deactivate it if you move to a directory without one.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! where is the 'chpwd` hook found? Is that another entry in the .zshrc?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative which sets an env variable when cd'ing into a virtualenv directory and checks if an active subdir is a child-directory of said virtualenv.

This will also deactivate when exiting or cd'ing to another directory.

This assumes you're using Pyenv to manage your Python installations, however you can change the `pyvenv.cfg` notation to anything else.

```bash
function cd() {

  builtin cd "$@"

    if [[ -f ./pyvenv.cfg ]] ; then
        export VENV_CURRENT=$PWD
        source ./bin/activate
    else
        if [[ $(env | fgrep VENV_CURRENT) ]]; then
            if ! [[ $(pwd | fgrep $VENV_CURRENT) ]]; then
                unset VENV_CURRENT
                deactivate
            fi
        fi
    fi
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Self promotion warning!

If you use oh-my-zsh I've forked and greatly improved (imo) a plugin that works for both bash and zsh and I included instructions for installing with oh-my-zsh

https://github.com/RobertDeRose/virtualenv-autodetect

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution, which:

- checks if already at the currently active `venv`, and do nothing in that case
- if there is a `venv` folder, deactivate the active one if there is one
- activate the new `venv` whatever if there was an old one or not.

In my `bash_aliases`:

```
function cd() {
    builtin cd "$@"

    if [ $(dirname "$VIRTUAL_ENV") == $(pwd) ] ; then
        # Already at the active virtual env
        return
    fi

    if [[ -d ./venv ]] ; then
        if type deactivate > /dev/null 2>&1 ; then
            printf "Deactivating virtualenv %s\n" "$VIRTUAL_ENV"
            deactivate
        fi

        source ./venv/bin/activate
        printf "Setting up   virtualenv %s\n" "$VIRTUAL_ENV"
    fi
}
```

Comment: Hi @Gauthier. This code only work if you enter in the root directory of target virtual environment. However, if you `cd` into any sub-directory of the target virtual environment, it still keeps the old virtual environment active.

Comment: @MS_ that's correct, it's not something I need. I guess it wouldn't be too hard to cd up all the way to / or until you find a dir venv? I considered it but will do it only when I have the need. More than that, it puts expectations on the name of the dir, whereas it should really try to be smarter and detect if a dir is a virtualenv environment by checking its content. But your answer doesn't do any of that either, am I wrong?

Comment: This doesn't deactivate when going into a non project directory (not necessarily important but I think it's nice to do).

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution:

1. If VIRTUAL_ENV is not set then:

   1. Check if we're inside a virtual env
   2. If yes, then activate it
2. Else (VIRTUAL_ENV is defined), check that the current folder starts with $VIRTUAL_ENV (removing the `/venv` part) and verify that the deactivate command exists

   1. Deactivate teh environment

This is the script:

```
function cd() {
  builtin cd $1

  if [[ -z "${VIRTUAL_ENV}" ]]; then
    if [[ -d ./venv && -f ./venv/bin/activate ]]; then
      source ./venv/bin/activate
    fi
  elif [[ ! "$(pwd)" == ${VIRTUAL_ENV:0:n-5}* && ! -z "$(command -v deactivate)" ]]; then
    deactivate
  fi
}
```

**Note**: You need to add this to `.bashrc`. If it doesn't work, check if your `.profile` is not overriding your command (it happened to me)

Comment: This doesn't support moving from one venv directory to another

Answer (score 0):

Based on @MS_'s solution:

```
function cd() {
  builtin cd "$@"

  ## If env folder is found then activate the vitualenv
  if [[ -d ./venv ]] ; then
    source ./venv/bin/activate
  fi

  if [[ -n "$VIRTUAL_ENV" ]] ; then
    ## check the current folder belong to earlier VIRTUAL_ENV folder
    # if yes then do nothing
    # else deactivate
      parentdir="$(dirname "$VIRTUAL_ENV")"
      if [[ "$PWD"/ != "$parentdir"/* ]] ; then
        deactivate
      fi
  fi
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used [direnv](https://direnv.net) in the past, as others have mentioned. Lyft use [aactivator](https://github.com/Yelp/aactivator) for this [exact scenario](https://eng.lyft.com/scaling-productivity-on-microservices-at-lyft-part-2-optimizing-for-fast-local-development-9f27a98b47ee).

> Once the venv is built it must be activated (added to $PATH). We use aactivator to automatically activate the venv each time a user enters the service directory and deactivates as they leave.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to execute `deactivate` on the directory where venv exists. When virtual environment is active you can deactivate anywhere.

So, say you have 2 venvs, `<somepath>/project1/venv` and `<somepath>/project2/venv`, and currently `project1/venv` is active.
If you want to switch `project2/venv`, do below.

```
cd project2
deactivate && source ./venv/bin/activate
```

It will deactivate previous one and activate current one.

Now the above you can just make an alias, or shell function in `~/.zshrc` as below:

```
function avenv(){
  deactivate
  source ./venv/bin/activate 
}
```

go the path where you want to activate the venv and just run `avenv`.

Python venv has a feature called --prompt, while creating venv you can mention the prompt, so that in the terminal you will understand which venv is active.

```
python3 -m venv venv --prompt PROJECT1_VENV
```

Now in terminal, it will come as `(PROJECT1_VENV) -> ~`

Answer (score 0):

#### `pyenv-virtualenv` + `pyenv local`

```
$ pyenv virtualenv 3.10.9 my-project
$ pyenv local my-project
```

That's is.

Every time you cd into that project directory `pyenv` automatically:

- checks the `.python-version` file made by `pyenv local`
- activates the virtual env from `$HOME/.pyenv/versions/3.10.9/envs/my-project`

##### Reference

- https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-virtualenv
- https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/blob/master/COMMANDS.md#pyenv-local
- https://realpython.com/intro-to-pyenv/#local

Answer (score 0):

The most upvoted answer didn't work for me. But adding this to my `.bashrc` did

```bash
# Automatically activate Python venv if it exists
auto_activate_venv() {
    if [ -e ".venv/bin/activate" ]; then
        source .venv/bin/activate
    elif [ "$VIRTUAL_ENV" != "" ] && [ ! -e "$PWD/.venv" ]; then
        deactivate
    fi
}

# Override the 'cd' command to call our function
cd() {
    builtin cd "$@" && auto_activate_venv
}

# If you use pushd/popd, you can override them too.
pushd() {
    builtin pushd "$@" && auto_activate_venv
}

popd() {
    builtin popd "$@" && auto_activate_venv
}
```