# change directory deactivates venv

Tags: python, cd, python-venv

Since last week, whenever I run `cd` from a virtual environment, it changes the directory, but  deactivates the venv. For example, I activate my virtual environment and try to `cd` to a subdirectory, this is what my terminal output looks like.

```
`MACBOOKPRO10:directory tgarza$ . .venv/bin/activate
(.venv) MACBOOKPRO10:directory tgarza$ cd settings/
MACBOOKPRO10:settings tgarza$`
```

I noticed this last week when running a script that requires venv, and it was unable to run through completion. Previously, when running the `cd` in venv, it stayed in venv and changed the directory so I'm not really sure what happened. Has anyone ever experienced something like this as I am not really finding anything about this?

Comment: This is more than likely just a display issue with your prompt.

Comment: Thanks for the response @jordanm! It looks like the solution for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45216663/how-to-automatically-activate-virtualenvs-when-cding-into-a-directory may have also worked for my issues as well.