# Pyenv: activate local venv

Tags: python, virtualenv, pyenv, python-poetry

I use [poetry](https://python-poetry.org/) to manage my projects dependencies and tests. I usually create a new virtual environment for each project, with a `.venv` directory inside of the project directory.

I would like to use pyenv virtualenv to automatically activate this projects virtualenv when inside the project directory as a `local` one, eg:

`pyenv virtualenv local <my venv that also lives inside of this project>`

Is this achievable, or do I have to create my virtualenvs inside the .pyenv directory?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to automatically activate virtualenvs when cd'ing into a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45216663/how-to-automatically-activate-virtualenvs-when-cding-into-a-directory)

Answer (score 0):

When inside the project directory, any command starting `poetry run` will be run inside the virtual environment created by poetry.

To avoid having to use `poetry run` before each command, `poetry shell` can be used to activate the virtual environment.